# How implement CSP on top of Agents in F#?

Tags: f#, agent

I have wondered if is possible (and advisable!) to implement CSP on top of F# Agents. I think if F# already have it and work well, then maybe is possible to just provide a API to mimic CSP with channels, ALT and similars...

The main trouble is that Agents are async, and CSP block. Or how implement CSP in F#?

P.D: I have found https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac but wish to know how implement it, for learning and to avoid dependencies if possible.

P.D 2: I have found a elixir sample at http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/10/playing-with-elixir-and-go-concurrency-models/ and erlang https://gist.github.com/kachayev/5426175.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis I think he's referring to Communicating Sequential Processes:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) has a nice section detailing key differences between CSP and the Actor Model (F# Agents are based on the Actor Model of concurrency).  The two differences that stand out that you'd absolutely need to address are synchronous vs. asynchronous communication and writing to channels vs. writing directly to the process.

It may be possible, but it looks to be difficult.  On the most fundamental level CSP requires completely synchronous communication between processes while the F# Agent (MailboxProcessor) is asynchronous, so you'd have to build a system which would force synchronous communication between F# Agents.  A possible solution might be to use the `PostAndReply` function.

The next major difference (and maybe the hardest to overcome): CSP writes to a specific channel while the F# actor model you write messages to a specific actor.  In other words, if you have two processes `A` and `B`:  with F# Agents `A` will send a message by explicitly saying `B.post(<msg>)`, while in CSP `A` would write a message to a channel named `chan` and `B` would be told to explicitly read from the channel named `chan` (note that in CSP the channels of communication are independent of the processes whereas in F# Agent model the channel of communication is identical to the receiving Agent).  This seems like a much more difficult difference to overcome.  Just throwing and idea out there (I have don't know if it would actually work well): one possibility might be to rethink what the F# Agent represents:  instead of having the Agent act as the process have Agents that act as the CSP channel.

For anyone curious about CSP, Clojure's core.async is based on CSP and Brave Clojure has a [pretty good tutorial](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/) that helps explain how CSP works.

Comment: I already understand the main diferences between CSP & Agents. I just like more the way CSP work and because F# *already* have agent wonder how  turn one in the other.

Comment: "instead of having the Agent act as the process have Agents that act as the CSP channel." I was thinking the same thing. In some respects it sounds like the channel would behave like a pub-sub.